# how can i convert json data to xml in pure lua without importing methods

Tags: lua

With the following JSON text I need to convert this text to an XML representation using Lua without importing any other dependencies or methods. What would the Lua code look like to do this transformation?

```
{"RS":"0","RSDESC":"SUCESS GAMES AVAILABLE","gamedata": [
    {"BetTypes":"0,0,0","BottomMessage":"WELCOME","DrawCloseTime":"57600","DrawDate":"09\/17\/2015","DrawID":"26091715","DrawNo":"109","DrawTime":"04:15 PM","GameGroupID":"1","LotName":"BANK3 - 04:00 PM","MRP":"10000","TktValidity":"17\/10\/2015"},
    {"BetTypes":"0,0,0","BottomMessage":"WELCOME","DrawCloseTime":"75600","DrawDate":"09\/17\/2015","DrawID":"27091715","DrawNo":"109","DrawTime":"09:15 PM","GameGroupID":"1","LotName":"BANK3 - 09:00 PM","MRP":"10000","TktValidity":"17\/10\/2015"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Since XML requires some sort of a schema, what are the tags supposed to look like and what is the DTD look like? You really do need to provide additional information for your question in order for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
J=[[
{"RS":"0","RSDESC":"SUCESS GAMES AVAILABLE","gamedata": [
    {"BetTypes":"0,0,0","BottomMessage":"WELCOME","DrawCloseTime":"57600","DrawDate":"09\/17\/2015","DrawID":"26091715","DrawNo":"109","DrawTime":"04:15 PM","GameGroupID":"1","LotName":"BANK3 - 04:00 PM","MRP":"10000","TktValidity":"17\/10\/2015"},
    {"BetTypes":"0,0,0","BottomMessage":"WELCOME","DrawCloseTime":"75600","DrawDate":"09\/17\/2015","DrawID":"27091715","DrawNo":"109","DrawTime":"09:15 PM","GameGroupID":"1","LotName":"BANK3 - 09:00 PM","MRP":"10000","TktValidity":"17\/10\/2015"}
    ]
}
]]

X=J:gsub('{','<ITEM>\n'):gsub('},?','</ITEM>\n')
X=X:gsub('"(%w-)"%s*:%s*(%b[])',
    function (k,v)
        return string.format("<%s>%s</%s>\n",k,v:sub(2,-2),k)
    end)
X=X:gsub('"(%w-)"%s*:%s*"(.-)",?',
    function (k,v)
        return string.format("<%s>%s</%s>\n",k,v,k)
    end)

print(X)
```